# Trying to validate form Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hello I'm trying to validate my form. I have form created with laravel4 and when I click submit button it always redirects me to /newsletter even if I enter all inputs. Where is the bug, could you help me please?

Routes:

```
Route::get('/newsletter', 'HomeController@signNewsletter');
Route::post('/sign', 'HomeController@sign');
```

Controllers:

```
public function signNewsletter() {
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home.newsletter');
}

public function sign(){
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required',
        'username' => 'required',           
        'surname' => 'required'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        // Validation has failed.
        return Redirect::to('/newsletter')->withErrors($validation);
    }else{
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/sign', 'method' =>'POST')) }}
  {{Form::token()}}
  {{Form::text('mail', null ,array( 
    'placeholder' => 'Twoj email'
  ))}}<br>
  {{Form::text('username', null ,array( 
    'placeholder' => 'Twoje imie'
  ))}}<br>
  {{Form::text('surname', null ,array(  
    'placeholder' => 'Twoje nazwisko'
  ))}}
  {{Form::submit('Click Me!')}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Debugging:

```
dd(Input::all());

// array(4) {
//  ["_token"]=> string(40) "77o2SwxRe7hhTWT6hV1MeIOi21GcuUbG1nsSD7B0"
//  ["mail"]=> string(6) "asdasd"
//  ["username"]=> string(8) "asdasdas"
//  ["surname"]=> string(6) "asdasd"
// }
```

Comment: Can you do a [`dd(Input::all())`](http://laravel.com/api/function-dd.html) before your validation to dump the contents and kill your script (so we make sure the contents are correct)?  Also seeing the form in `home.newsletter` could help.

Comment: This is what I got: array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "77o2SwxRe7hhTWT6hV1MeIOi21GcuUbG1nsSD7B0" ["mail"]=> string(6) "asdasd" ["username"]=> string(8) "asdasdas" ["surname"]=> string(6) "asdasd" }

Comment: you're returning an error message to the page - what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using "email" as a rule, but "mail" as the field name

Comment: Didn't notice, thanks :) I have one more question If I validation fail how can I show errors in /newsletter page after redirected?